# Smart truncation of filename in CSS

Tags: css, overflow

I'm trying to make a custom truncation of text that represents a filename that always shows the file extension, but hides part of the name if there's not enough space. For example, the filename is `testtesttest.xml`. If there's not enough space, I want it to display something like `tes...xml`

I've been playing with `text-overflow: ellipsis`, but I didn't get any result. It either truncates the whole line, or doesn't truncate at all.

```js
export default function FilenameTruncate(props) {
    const [name, extension] = props.filename.split('.')
    return (
        <div className="filename-container">
            <div className="filename-text">
                <span>{name}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="filename-ext">
                <span>.{extension}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

```css
.filename-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.filename-text {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.filename-ext {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add an `overflow` property and a `width` or `max-width`:

```css
.filename-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.filename-text {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 3em;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    overflow: hidden;
}

.filename-ext {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="filename-container">
    <div class="filename-text">
        <span>longfilename</span>
    </div>
    <div class="filename-ext">
        <span>.ext</span>
    </div>
</div>
```